# parseInt with jQuery

Tags: jquery

Can someone help me figuring out why the following jQuery code doesn't work?
I want to return a integer from a user input.

```
var test = parseInt($("#testid"));
```

Comment: Please define "doesn't work." What do you expect to happen, and what really happens?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

```
var test = parseInt($("#testid").val(), 10);
```

You have to tell it you want the `value` of the input you are targeting.

And also, always provide the second argument (radix) to `parseInt`.  It tries to be too clever and autodetect it if not provided and can lead to unexpected results.

Providing `10` assumes you are wanting a base 10 number.

Comment: You should always specify the radix when calling `parseInt`.

Comment: What about compatibility  of parseInt ?

Answer (score 18):

Two issues:

1. You're passing the jQuery wrapper of the element into `parseInt`, which isn't what you want, as `parseInt` will call `toString` on it and get back `"[object Object]"`. You need to use [`val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) or [`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) or something (depending on what the element is) to get the string you want.
2. You're not telling `parseInt` what radix (number base) it should use, which puts you at risk of odd input giving you odd results when `parseInt` guesses which radix to use.

Fix if the element is a form field:

```
//                               vvvvv-- use val to get the value
var test = parseInt($("#testid").val(), 10);
//                                    ^^^^-- tell parseInt to use decimal (base 10)
```

Fix if the element is something else and you want to use the text within it:

```
//                               vvvvvv-- use text to get the text
var test = parseInt($("#testid").text(), 10);
//                                     ^^^^-- tell parseInt to use decimal (base 10)
```

Answer (score 8):

```
var test = parseInt($("#testid").val());
```

Comment: You should always specify the radix when calling `parseInt`.