# How to parseInt a jQuery value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add +1 to a value but I can't figure out how is the value define. Is it a jQuery object ?

```
   var value = $(this).attr('data-id'); /* return a number between 0 to xx */
   var val = (value+1);
```

I tried too : `var val = (paseInt(value)+1);` with no more effectiveness ..

It tells me that val = 0 when it should be equal to 1 and val = 1 when it should be equal to 2 etc..

A quick help would be greatly appreciate here :)

Comment: check dis http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9775375/parseint-with-jquery

Comment: Can you post your html code? And also try with accessing id using  $(this).data('id');

Comment: what is coming inside the value variable

Comment: @Light This is a good trail; It not the value i'm looking for but something like this should work

Comment: typo in your parseInt. You have written paseInt which should be parseInt.

Comment: @RohitArora Sometimes I feel stupid ...

Comment: Also, you may want to add the base to `parseInt` (ie, `parseInt(value, 10)`. Not all browsers assume it will be 10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try parsing to `int` as soon as you fetch data as below:

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/0tLdre3s/)**

**LOCAL DEMO**

```js
$('.specldiv').on('click',function(){
   var value = parseInt($(this).attr('data-id')); 
   var vals = (value+1); 
    alert(vals);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="specldiv" data-id="1">Div with id data-id 1</div>
<div class="specldiv" data-id="0">Div with id data-id 0</div>
<div class="specldiv" data-id="2">Div with id data-id 2</div>
```

Comment: Strangely working in your code but not in mine; I'll comme back when I understand why

Comment: may be as @RohitArora said in his comments you have typo in `parseInt`, you have written `paseInt`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var value = 0;
value = $(this).attr('data-id');
```

Comment: Nup not changing anything.. I've tried with int value = 0 too.

Comment: Setting the variable to `0` first doesn't do anything, because that value is discarded (overwritten) when you do the next assignment.

Comment: when you assign 0 to variable at declaration time its take this variable as int.then u can parse int and perform calculations..

Answer (score 0):

For data attribute you can just try $(this).data("id") than you can perform following

```
var value = $(this).data("id");
var val = value + 1;
```

Comment: Nop beacause data("id") wiil be different than Attribute("data-id") Dont ask me why but it's true ;) You can check in your consol if you want

Comment: that's because if you use `<!DOCTYPE html>` at top `$('this').data('id')` will be recognized since `data-*` is an `html5` attribute

Comment: @Baldráni - The html attribute contains a string. `.attr("data-id")` returns that attribute as a string. But `.data('id')` will return that attribute but will attempt to guess the datatype and do a cast, so if the value can be converted to a number that's what `.data("id")` will return.

Answer (score 0):

Use this javascript hack:)

```
var value = +($(this).attr('data-id')); /* return a number between 0 to xx */
var val = value+1;
```

When you use "+" without blanks, before string that contains number, your string transforms to number.